# Excel add-in: capture changes made to an excel file before it is saved

Tags: .net, vsto

I'm developing an Excel add-in that performs some actions on Application.WorkbookBeforeSave event. When user makes changes to a file and clicks "Save" I want to capture new file (with changes) and upload it somewhere instead of saving it on disk. How can I get this file's content if the file is not and will not be saved? I couldn't find any Content property on Excel.Workbook object or anything like it.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your use case: you want to intercept save, so if I create a new file, edit it and save, it never saves on my PC but is "saved" on a different machine. Is that right?

Comment: may also be saved on your machine, but additionaly it is saved somewhere else